# Angular: How to set downloading spinner when there can be n-number of items that can be downloaded

Tags: angular

I have n-number of items that can be downloaded dependent on the user. Normally when I have one item I would create a variable set that one to false and when the subscribe starts set it to true and when it finishes back to false. Now I have to do it for multiple items that the user self can download so setting the variables in the component is not an option. What would be the right way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I would bind the download event of each item to a boolean array, set to false. 
Once the user select what to download, set it to true, and when finished back to false.

Then you can bind the spinner to a method that checks any of the array elements is true.